# Combine records to show start date and end date SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

Just need a bit of help on how to solve the issue I have.

Basically, I have a set of data example below:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+  
| Class ID | Start date | End date  |  
+----------+------------+-----------+  
|    12345 | 1-Jan-21   | 2-Jan-21  |  
|    12345 | 3-Jan-21   | 4-Jan-21  |  
|    12345 | 5-Jan-21   | 6-Jan-21  |  
|    12345 | 7-Jan-21   | 8-Jan-21  |  
|    67890 | 17-Jan-21  | 25-Jan-21 |  
|    67890 | 25-Jan-21  | 26-Jan-21 |  
|    67890 | 26-Jan-21  | 31-Jan-21 |  
+----------+------------+-----------+
```

I would like to group the row with the same class ID but only showing the minimum start date and the maximum end date on one row. Like the table below:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+  
| Class ID | Start Date | End Date  |   
+----------+------------+-----------+  
|    12345 | 1-Jan-21   | 8-Jan-21  |  
|    67890 | 17-Jan-21  | 31-Jan-21 |  
+----------+------------+-----------+
```

How would I query it?

Thank you!

Comment: What if you have the same class id but there's a gap, e.g. one more row for 11th-18th Jan 2021? Would you still have one row in the output, or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select class_id, min(start_date), max(end_date)
from t
group by class_id;
```